# How to load XML data in jQueryEasyUI treegrid

Tags: jquery-easyui

I have recently started using easyUI tree grid,which by default easyui consume json .Could any one please provide me with a sample to load an XML data through a link to xml file or URL.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think u have XML data in the Array format then u can create JSON data using associated array and then use

var Data=JSON.stringify(AssociatedArrayData); 
var finalData=JSON.parse(Data);

finalData contains json format data.